# Force discord to display failed interaction message

Tags: python, discord, discord.js, discord.py

Discord will automatically time out and trigger a custom "This interaction failed" message if the application fails to respond to an interaction within 3s.

I am however running some slightly longer tasks, so I'm calling the `ctx.defer()` method, which gives me more time to respond and displays a "<application_name> is thinking..." animation discord-side.

Should my task raise some internal exception, I'd like to manually trigger the "This interaction failed" message. Does the discord API expose a method to do so?

[image]

*The message I'm trying to trigger*

A dummy example, using `discord-py-slash-command`:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash import SlashCommand, SlashContext

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
slash = SlashCommand(bot)

@slash.slash(name="test")
async def _test(ctx: SlashContext):
    await ctx.defer()
    try:
        assert 1==2
    except AssertionError:
        # Somehow trigger the error message

bot.run("discord_token")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation states, that defering a message will allow an update of the message for up to 15 minutes. There is no intented way of failing the interaction early, however you could try sending an invalid/broken response on purpose and see if that invalidates the pending interaction.

However this is far from good practice and not possible within the implementation limits of the `discord-py-slash-command` library.

I would recommend to manually invoke an error response to show the user a better error response. A failed interaction can have many reasons from buggy code to complete unavailability of your service and doesn't really help the user.

#### Expected errors

You can simply respond with a hidden user message.

```
ctx.send('error description', hidden=True)
return
```

For this to work, you must first defer the message in a hidden stage aswell `ctx.defer(hidden=True)`. If you want the final answer to be seen for all users on the server, you can either send a normal message on-top (`ctx.channel.send`) or you can show the error message as a public message, by using the 'normal' defer.

#### Unexpected errors

To catch unexpected errors, I'd suggest listening to the `on_slash_command_error` event handler.

```
@client.event
async def on_slash_command_error(ctx, error):

    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('You do not have permission to execute this command', hidden=True)

    else:
       await ctx.send('An unexpected error occured. Please contact the bot developer', hidden=True)
       raise error  # this will show some debug print in the console, when debugging
```

Note that the response will only be hidden if the previous defer was called as `ctx.defer(hidden=True)`. If `ctx.defer()` was used, the execution won't fail, and a warning will be printed to your console.

That way the calling method can decide if unexpected errors are visible for all users, by choosing the corresponding `defer` arguments.

The part of the `discord-py-slash-command` documentation where it talks about defer: https://discord-py-slash-command.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html